# Parallel processing of items available in a list<string> using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#

I m trying to develop a network monitor for my Project. I am using Parallel.ForEach for parallelly sending the ping to the all the IP Addressess listed in the List IPListAll.

I want to work on the Reply received from all the PCs, however my code never reaches MessageBox.Show and DisplayChangeOnReply function. I am stuck here. Please help, i dont know what i m doing wrong. My Code is appended below for refrence.

```
while(true)
{
    object pinglock = new object();
    Parallel.ForEach(IPListAll,ipaddr =>
    {
        lock(pinglock)
        {
            reply = Ping.Send(ipaddr,500);    // this line is being executed always
            MessageBox.Show(ipaddr);        // Execution not reaching here
        }
        DisplayChangeOnReply(reply,ipaddr); // Execution nor reaching here
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the point of using a parallel construct if the very first thing the loop will do is block the other threads from running until most of the work is done? Just use a normal `foreach` or don't use shared state

Comment: And this `while(true)` perhaps you want some timer to run the ping every x second instead of flooding with ping.

Comment: You are locking the object `pinglock` inside the `Parallel` loop, which means, only one action will be executed at the same time because each thread will wait until the lock get released, defeating the whole purpose of the `Parallel` loop, as Camilo mentioned.

Comment: removing lock this exception is thrown System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
 
  An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method.

Comment: thats why i used lock in the Parallel.ForEach

Comment: the `lock` is making the `Parallel.ForEach` pointless.

Comment: whatever the case may be.. i didnt get the solution yet.. i m still stuck here.. and removing lock throws an exception as i had already mentioned... please help me out

Comment: `thats why i used lock in the Parallel.ForEach` <= the point of the comment was that this code block should *not use* `Parallel.ForEach`. Use `foreach(var ipaddr in IPListAll) {...` instead.

Comment: the lock is not making the Parrallel.Foreach pointless, as long as there are things happening outside of the lock. 
Make sure the Ping is not throwing any errors, and that you're not in a context that blocks the UI thread. That would cause a deadlock w/ the MessageBox.Show()

Comment: also, take MessageBox.Show() outside of the lock.

Comment: What is the code of `Ping.Send`? given the error *An asynchronous call is already in progress* I have reason to think you might not need a Parallel loop but a set of tasks. Also, what is in `DisplayChangeOnReply`? You cannot access the UI from a non-GUI thread.